# Quasi-determinant of $2n\times 2$ matrix as a difference between two dot products

Tags: vectors, determinant

Consider the $ 2n \times 2 $ matrix $ \begin{pmatrix} \bf a  & \bf b \\ \bf c & \bf d \end{pmatrix}  $ where $ \bf a $, $ \bf b $, $ \bf c $ and $ \bf d $ are $ n \times 1 $.  Define the scalar $ q = \bf a ^\rm T \bf d - \bf b ^ \rm T \bf c $.  For $ n=1 $  $ q $ is equivalent to the ordinary determinant.  For $ n>1 $ $ q $ is reminiscent of the determinant of a $ 2 \times 2 $ matrix.  Are quasi-determinants like $ q $ used anywhere?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://www.google.it/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi4zYC8y8DYAhWR3KQKHcwYAGEQFggnMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmath.meta.stackexchange.com%2Fquestions%2F5020%2Fmathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference&usg=AOvVaw1zLdIXv6Cu4GY53kDgHoTt) to format your questinon.